# How to call state from base class in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I'm building an app with ReactJS, and created a base class called ListBaseComponent for paging. My other class derive from that class but I can not call base state with this.state.SomeState. How can I do that?

```
export class ListBaseComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    filter: {
      paging: {
        pageSize: 10,
        currentPage: 1,
        rowsCount: 0
      }
    }
  };
export class CountryList extends ListBaseComponent {
  ...
  total={this.state.filter.paging.rowsCount} //TypeError: Cannot read property 'paging' of undefined
}
```

Comment: `ListBaseComponent` is `BaseComponent` ?

Comment: Dacre Denny: oh yes, thank you. I edited that.

Answer (score 0):

You would pass them in as props

```
import CountryList from './path/to/country/list/component';

export class BaseComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    filter: {
      paging: {
        pageSize: 10,
        currentPage: 1,
        rowsCount: 0
      }
    }

   render() {
       return(
           <div className="wrapper">
                <CountryList
                    filter={this.state.filter}
                />
           </div>
       )
   }
};
```

then inside of CountryList you can call

```
export class CountryList extends Component {
  ...
  total={this.props.filter ? this.props.filter.paging.rowsCount : null}
}
```

Comment: Actually I have some other functions in parent class. But that's great. I'll try. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can always get access to the parent property through child class, may be you forgot to call `super()` in the Child class `constructor`.

Also make sure to initialise the parent state with `this.state` so that the child instance can have access to this property.

```
import React from "react";

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      filter: {
        page: 1
      }
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        I am a parent component .<ChildApp />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return <h1> I am a child component {this.state.filter.page} </h1>;
  }
}
```

```
import reactDOM from 'react-dom';
reactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'll try again.